# jQuery Moving Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Hey guys im looking for a jQuery powered image slider that does same exact function as this one, but not in flash:

http://www.medievaltimes.com/

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific, what do you mean image slider? Are you talking about once that page is loaded, the way the slide-show cross-fades images and zooms in on a specific portion of the current one?

Comment: ya, when the page is loaded then the slider kicks in, cross fades and zooms throughout the image

Answer (score 2):

Not to be mean but... google it:

http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/slideshow%20type%3Aproject_project

http://webanthology.net/1522-jquery-image-slideshowslider-tutorials-and-plugins-for-your-next-projects/2009/11/24/

pretty sure there is an auto-slideshow in there.

check also this: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/